# TypeError While loading the files

Tags: python, typeerror

```
train_dir = os.path.join(X_train,y_train)
test_dir = os.path.join(X_test, y_test)

if not os.path.exists(train_dir):
   os.makedirs(train_dir)

if not os.path.exists(test_dir):
   os.makedirs(test_dir)
```

This is my piece of code to load the files the of train and test,  but got the error of type;

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-144de685caf8> in <module>
----> 1 train_dir = os.path.join(X_train,y_train)
      2 test_dir = os.path.join(X_test, y_test)
      3 
      4 if not os.path.exists(train_dir):
      5     os.makedirs(train_dir)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/posixpath.py in join(a, *p)
     78     will be discarded.  An empty last part will result in a path that
     79     ends with a separator."""
---> 80     a = os.fspath(a)
     81     sep = _get_sep(a)
     82     path = a

TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list
```

I do all the things which can do this to correct, please help me out.

Comment: What is the datatype of `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_test`, `y_test`? The `os.path.join` function takes in strings.

Comment: ( .csv )  files  both.

Comment: Reading the error, they seem to be of type list. Please add the output of type(X_train) to the question. Or better yet, add the code of how the variable X_train is being assigned